# Q: my subscriptions don't show up in the new developer portal, but are present in legacy

Tags: azure-api-management

I have created an API in APIM, and after signing up a test user through the portal (tried both new and legacy) subscribed to an exposed API. My subscription (with keys) is present in the legacy portal Profile page, but not in the new one. Am I missing something?
Also, in the new portal, I can see the subscription keys when on the APIs > Operation > "Try it" page, despite the subscription itself and the keys missing under my Profile.

***Legacy screenshot***
[image]

***New portal screenshot***

[image]

***Azure portal screenshot from Product>Subscriptions***

[image]

***"Try it" page in the new portal***

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue.

After raising a support ticket, I get that this is a known issue and related fix has not been released yet. Planned fix available time is the end of this week 31/5.

So you can check if your subscription exists in the new developer portal on next Monday.